# How to resize a PyQt5 stacked widget as per window size in PyQt5 Python?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qtablewidget, qstackedwidget

I am designing a `ui` in `qt-desginer`. I have to create a UI which has a side menu bar with buttons and whichever button is pressed, its appropriate data will be shown on right side.

To design this, I have I have placed two `QFrame` in `horizontal layout` on central widget. I have reduced the width of left side `QFrame` named `side_menu_bar` and thus it has become the side menu bar. On the right side `QFrame` named `content_area`, I have placed a `stackedWidget` with multiple pages.

Now whatever data I want to show on `stackedWidget` has to cover the complete area of `content_area` and thus I have used a `vertical layout` on `stackedWidget`. On the `page_2` of `stackedWidget`, I have placed a `tablewidget`. This `page_2` will be shown if a user clicks `pushButton` on side menu bar.

Below is the python code of the UI file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'home2.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.0
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_home_window(object):
    def setupUi(self, home_window):
        home_window.setObjectName("home_window")
        home_window.resize(1216, 613)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(home_window)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.layoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.layoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(2, 0, 1211, 611))
        self.layoutWidget.setObjectName("layoutWidget")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.side_menu_bar = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.layoutWidget)
        self.side_menu_bar.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        self.side_menu_bar.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 16777215))
        self.side_menu_bar.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.side_menu_bar.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.side_menu_bar.setObjectName("side_menu_bar")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.side_menu_bar)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 100, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.side_menu_bar)
        self.content_area = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.layoutWidget)
        self.content_area.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(170, 255, 0);")
        self.content_area.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.content_area.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.content_area.setObjectName("content_area")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.content_area)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(9, 9, 1071, 591))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.stackedWidget.setObjectName("stackedWidget")
        self.page = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page.setObjectName("page")
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page)
        self.page_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_2.setObjectName("page_2")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.page_2)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1071, 591))
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(50)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(50)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_2)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.stackedWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.content_area)
        home_window.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(home_window)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(home_window)

    def retranslateUi(self, home_window):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        home_window.setWindowTitle(_translate("home_window", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("home_window", "PushButton"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    home_window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_home_window()
    ui.setupUi(home_window)
    home_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

and below is how I am using it in `app.py`

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from src.home2_ui import Ui_home_window


class HomeWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_home_window):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.home_ui = Ui_home_window()
        self.home_ui.setupUi(self)
        self.showMaximized()

        layout = self.home_ui.horizontalLayout_2
        self.home_ui.centralwidget.setLayout(layout)

        self.home_ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.show_page2)

    def show_page2(self):
        layout2 = self.home_ui.verticalLayout
        layout2.addWidget(self.home_ui.stackedWidget)
        self.home_ui.content_area.setLayout(layout2)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
main_window = HomeWindow()
main_window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Now as per my understanding, I want to show my application full screen and want to fit the complete area of the window. So for that I have attached the `horizontal layout` to `central widget`:

```
layout = self.home_ui.horizontalLayout_2
self.home_ui.centralwidget.setLayout(layout)
```

Now in order to make table widget cover the complete area of stacked widget I have used below code on button press event:

```
layout2 = self.home_ui.verticalLayout
layout2.addWidget(self.home_ui.stackedWidget)
self.home_ui.content_area.setLayout(layout2)
```

As per my understanding whatever widget we want to show in stacked widget has to cover the complete area of  stacked widget and thus I have attached stacked widget to vertical layout and then I have set the layout of content area to layout2 (which is vertical layout). Now by doing this, if I click on the button to show table widget, nothing is getting shown:

[image]

Here I have a question, when I click on pushbutton to show table widget, table widget is not shown but instead a blank window is shown which is also covering the side menu bar.?

If I replace the above code to:

```
layout2 = self.home_ui.verticalLayout
layout2.addWidget(self.home_ui.tableWidget)
self.home_ui.content_area.setLayout(layout2)
```

so In this case I have added table widget to vertical layout instead of stacked widget. Below is the output:

[image]

It does shows table but only on half screen. Also it has removed the side menu bar too.

I am not able to fully understand how to use the `layout` when using `stacked widgets`. Can anyone please guide me on how to do this. Please help. Thanks

Here is the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1luayH4C8E6w9veUuSH2LwrAjTXQ4W9m5/view?usp=sharing) to download the `home2.ui` file

[image]

[image]

**Update:**

I have finally been able to resolve this. I have used horizontal layout which is acting as a base layout and it has two childrens `content area` and `side menu bar`. Both `content area` and `side menu bar` have vertical layout. In `side menu bar` I can add as many as I want and it will be auto aligned due to vertical layout. In `content area` I have added stacked widget which is again a child of vertical layout. In page 2 of stacked widget, I had to add another vertical layout and then added table widget. Now it showing perfectly.

Below is all the code:

UI CODE:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'home5.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.0
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_home_window(object):
    def setupUi(self, home_window):
        home_window.setObjectName("home_window")
        home_window.resize(1196, 573)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(home_window)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 1181, 561))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.base_h_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.base_h_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.base_h_layout.setSpacing(0)
        self.base_h_layout.setObjectName("base_h_layout")
        self.side_menu_bar = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.widget)
        self.side_menu_bar.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 16777215))
        self.side_menu_bar.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.side_menu_bar.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.side_menu_bar.setObjectName("side_menu_bar")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.side_menu_bar)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.menu_bar_v_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.menu_bar_v_layout.setContentsMargins(10, 10, 10, 10)
        self.menu_bar_v_layout.setSpacing(10)
        self.menu_bar_v_layout.setObjectName("menu_bar_v_layout")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.side_menu_bar)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.menu_bar_v_layout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.menu_bar_v_layout)
        self.base_h_layout.addWidget(self.side_menu_bar)
        self.content_area = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.widget)
        self.content_area.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.content_area.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.content_area.setObjectName("content_area")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.content_area)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.content_area_v_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.content_area_v_layout.setSpacing(0)
        self.content_area_v_layout.setObjectName("content_area_v_layout")
        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self.content_area)
        self.stackedWidget.setObjectName("stackedWidget")
        self.page = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page.setObjectName("page")
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page)
        self.page_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_2.setObjectName("page_2")
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_2)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setObjectName("verticalLayout_4")
        self.table_v_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.table_v_layout.setSpacing(0)
        self.table_v_layout.setObjectName("table_v_layout")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.page_2)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(50)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(50)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.table_v_layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.verticalLayout_4.addLayout(self.table_v_layout)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_2)
        self.content_area_v_layout.addWidget(self.stackedWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.content_area_v_layout)
        self.base_h_layout.addWidget(self.content_area)
        home_window.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(home_window)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(home_window)

    def retranslateUi(self, home_window):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        home_window.setWindowTitle(_translate("home_window", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("home_window", "PushButton"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    home_window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_home_window()
    ui.setupUi(home_window)
    home_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

app.py:

```
class HomeWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_home_window):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.home_ui = Ui_home_window()
        self.home_ui.setupUi(self)
        self.showMaximized()

        base_layout = self.home_ui.base_h_layout
        self.home_ui.centralwidget.setLayout(base_layout)

        side_menu_v_layout = self.home_ui.menu_bar_v_layout
        self.home_ui.side_menu_bar.setLayout(side_menu_v_layout)

        content_v_layout = self.home_ui.content_area_v_layout
        self.home_ui.content_area.setLayout(content_v_layout)

        table_layout = self.home_ui.table_v_layout
        self.home_ui.page_2.setLayout(table_layout)

        self.home_ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.show_page2)

    def show_page2(self):
        self.home_ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.home_ui.page_2)
```

and this is how the `qt-designer` object inspector looks like:

[image]

Thanks to @allec and @musicamante.

Comment: As already suggested in at least another one of your questions, you have to use layout managers correctly (which means that you need to [read their documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html). Set a layout for content_area, setup_page, report_page and side_menu_bar.

Comment: @musicamante I have updated the question with new details, can you please have a look at it

Comment: Please don't edit the question to answer yourself, it only makes the whole topic confusing. You either create a new answer (if it actually *is* a new answer) or add relevant information to an existing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `side_menu_bar` does not appear because it has no layout manager to determine a proper size. Even though you added a child button directly to the frame, it will not resize accordingly unless you explicitly tell it to. You have a lot of extra placeholder QWidgets, particularly `layoutWidget`, `verticalLayoutWidget`, and `page_2` that are making this design more complicated than necessary. Any kind of widget can be added directly to the layout or stacked widget. The two QFrames should each have a layout only containing the child widgets.

```
class Ui_home_window(object):
    def setupUi(self, home_window):
        home_window.setObjectName("home_window")
        home_window.resize(1216, 613)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(home_window)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.side_menu_bar = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        self.side_menu_bar.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        self.side_menu_bar.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 16777215))
        self.side_menu_bar.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.side_menu_bar.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.side_menu_bar.setObjectName("side_menu_bar")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.side_menu_bar)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.side_menu_bar)
        vbox.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.side_menu_bar)
        
        self.content_area = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        self.content_area.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(170, 255, 0);")
        self.content_area.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.content_area.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.content_area.setObjectName("content_area")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.content_area)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
        self.stackedWidget.setObjectName("stackedWidget")
        self.page = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page.setObjectName("page")
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page)
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(50)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(50)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.stackedWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.content_area)
        home_window.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(home_window)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(home_window)

    def retranslateUi(self, home_window):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        home_window.setWindowTitle(_translate("home_window", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("home_window", "PushButton"))
```

There is no need to further set layouts to widgets in `HomeWindow`, you can switch to the other page with `QStackedWidget.setCurrentIndex()`.

```
class HomeWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_home_window):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.home_ui = Ui_home_window()
        self.home_ui.setupUi(self)
        self.showMaximized()

        self.home_ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.show_page2)

    def show_page2(self):
        self.home_ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)
```

Before pressing button:

[image]

After pressing button:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible for you to share the UI file because I wanted to see how widgets are arranged in Object Inspector in qt designer.

Comment: @SAndrew I don't use Qt Designer

Comment: Okay. I am understanding the code and will update you if I have any questions. Thanks

Comment: I have gone through your code and have got the idea. I have added a photo of UI design in question, can you please check and confirm if my understanding is correct or not.

Comment: I have been able to resolve this. Not sure why I had to add another vertical layout in page 2 of stacked widget, only then the table was covering all the area. I have updated the questions. Thanks